# Mifare 1k : use on the same sector only key A for one block and only key B for another block

Tags: authentication, key, mifare

I want on a Mifare 1K card make the data of the block 1 on the sector 0 only readable by the key A, and the data of the block 2 on the sector 0 only readable by the B key (For this problem i don't care about the writing right on those block)

Regarding the data block access bit rules from the data sheet for Mifare 1K
[Table of access bit rules for data block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ofbn.png)

I have a doubt about one thing. You have 3 possibilities (Never, Key B, Key A|B). Key A|B means Key A or Key B.

Is that means that if your key B is not readable on the sector trailer (so active) you can do with the Key B every action that the Key A can do ?

So it's impossible on the same sector to have one block readable **only** by the key A and another block **only** readable by the Key B

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The whole sector is controlled by the last block of each sector in Mifare 1k.Therefore, it is impossible to have one block readable only by key A and another only by key B.

The only solution left is to use blocks from two different sectors to fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Using correct access bits combination. So playing it you can set read block 0 with key A, write with key B, read/write block 1 by key B and so on.